# how to add all days of month into a Combo Box in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

> hello, i want to add all days of a month into a combo box and i do not know how to do it.
> this is the xaml combobox code section :

```
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dt}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                            
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
```

> and this is the C# code to fill it:

```
        List<datepick> datepicks = new List<datepick>();

        
        datepicks.Add(new datepick() { dt = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        
        

        cob_date_select.ItemsSource = datepicks;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to get the dates like

```
private void BindDatesToComboBox()
        {
            List<string> datesOfMonth = new List<string>();
            datesOfMonth.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month))  // Days: 1, 2 ... 31 etc.
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, day).ToLongDateString()) // Map each day to a date
                    .ToList()); // Load dates into a list

            cob_date_select.ItemsSource = datesOfMonth;
        }
```

and then simply reduce the xaml code to

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cob_date_select" FontSize="20" Height="30">
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a collection to feed combo box. It's worth to mention that UI part needs representation of the date (you want to use `ToLongDateString()` which uses application current culture), but from other side probably you will need to manipulate on selected date (using string representation will be cumbersome).

To have string representation of the `DateTime` and easy way of gathering object I made a wrapper.

```
<!-- XAML; DataContext is set to the instance of ExampleViewModel class -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"/>
```

```
// ExampleViewModel.cs
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public IList<UiDateTimeWrapper> Days { get; set; }

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        this.Days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 12)).Select(x =>
            new UiDateTimeWrapper { 
                Date = new DateTime(2020, 12, x) 
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
// UiDateTimeWrapper.cs
public class UiDateTimeWrapper
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Date.ToLongDateString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve that by using the following code in the codebehind file:

There is a method that takes the year and a month as input and returns a list of dates.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dates = GetDates(2020, 12);

        cob_date_select.ItemsSource = dates;
        cob_date_select.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        cob_date_select.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        cob_date_select.SelectedValue = "2"; // Second day of month
    }

    public static List<ComboDate> GetDates(int year, int month)
    {
        var dates = new List<ComboDate>();

        // Loop from the first day of the month until we hit the next month, moving forward a day at a time
        for (var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1); date.Month == month; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            dates.Add(new ComboDate { Id = date.Day, Value = date.Day });
        }

        return dates;
    }

    public class ComboDate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Probably `Id` and `Value` should not hold same data.

Comment: ty for your answer

Comment: this method is really useful too.